# How to correctly use Django reverse FK lookup to show instances of the child model in CBV

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I have two models, field of one of them pointing to the other as shown below:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_company_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, ...)
    
class Company(models.Model):
    company_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, ...)
    group_company = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="related_grp_company", ...)
```

I am trying to get all the **Companies** that have been created for a particular **Group**. So I am trying to get the `company_id` (and other) values in Djnago `UpdateView` as a list in the template. My CBV is as shown:

```
class GroupCompanyChangeView(UpdateView):
    template_name =  ...
    model = Group
    form_class = ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('group_list')

    grp_coy_units = Group.objects.prefetch_related('related_grp_company') # I am trying to get the values of `company_id` in the template but nothing is displayed.
```

**Could somebody please let me know how to get this to work?**

### Update

As explained (@Mahmoud Adel), I have modified my `UpdateView` as shown below:

```
class GroupCompanyChangeView(UpdateView):
    template_name =  ...
    model = Group
    form_class = ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('group_list')

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return Group.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

And then in the template, I am doing:

`{{ group.related_grp_company }}`

With this I am getting an output of `<app>.Company.None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: After testing on my local env to solve the problems reported in the comments, this is the final answer**

You should override `get_object()`

```
def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return Group.objects.prefetch_related('related_grp_company').get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        except:
            return None
```

Note that order matter here in the above query, doing `prefetch_related` before `get` fixes the error for `'Group' object has no attribute 'prefetch_related'`.

Also, you can drop using `prefetch_related` and only do `get` from the above query and it will work too, but using `prefetch_related` is suggested to optimize performance as you will fetch the related companies every time

Then at your `template` you can simply call `related_grp_company.all` from the object, let's say that you are passing the current `Group` object as `group` to your template, so it should like `group.related_grp_company.all`, this is a `QuerySet` list, so loop over it or do whatever you want.

for ex:

```
{%for d in object.related_grp_company.all%}
<h1>{{ d.company_id }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Because we didn't add `all` we were getting`<app>.Company.None` earlier

Tip:

`related_name` is used for the **reverse relation**, I would suggest renaming it to `companies` so it would be more clearer, for ex:

```
group_company = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name="companies", ...)
```

so using it later will be like `group.companies()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am getting error `Company matching query does not exist.` Am I missing something? I have put the override in the ** GroupCompanyChangeView**  `UpdateView`.

Comment: this may be raised because a company with the requested id doesn't exist, did you try using `get_object_or_404()` as shown in the answer?

Comment: Actually as I have already put in my question, I am trying to get all **companies** in the **Group**. And yes, there are **companies** under the **Group**. Anyway, using `get_object_or_404()` I am getting error `'Company' object has no attribute 'prefetch_related'`.

Comment: ah sorry my fault, The answer was for getting all group objects related to company I have updated the answer for `Group`

Comment: I may not have understood it correctly, but I am getting `<app_name>.Company.None` in the template. Just to demonstrate it the way I have done it (and that I understood your explanation correctly), I am updating my question above. Please check.

Comment: The reason for `None` at `template` is that, the related data is not loaded by django as it ORM is `lazy loading` by default and a template won't make a new query to get anything, I have updated the answer with `prefetch_related` to fix that

Comment: Nope. The same problem persists `'Group' object has no attribute 'prefetch_related'`!!

Comment: I know why this is happening now, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818183/4984493

Comment: can you try using `select_related` instead of `prefetch_related`?

Comment: Same problem **`'Group' object has no attribute 'select_related'`**!!

Comment: I will try it at my local env and get back to you

Comment: I have tested on my local env and updated my answer with the final answer, everything should work fine now

Comment: As you have noticed my comment at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30348720), in fact the issue was resolved yesterday itself with the help of this instant answer. However, it was thanks to you that helped me majorly in my query. **Another matter. In the `get_object` override, I could do without the`try` /  `except` bits**. Doesn't throw any problem. Marking your answer. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: I'm happy that things are working smoothly with you now! thank you too and have a nice day :)